# RxJava with SQLite to dynamically update Chat UI

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a chat app which communicates with the nodejs server (written by me) using socket.io. Multiple people can chat with one another on a one-to-one basis. The UI of the app is like WhatsApp. There are different `Chat Threads` where `Users` can exchange `Chat Messages`. These need to be stored on an SQLite db.

To ensure the app works even when it is switched off, I have initiated the socket.io connection in a service.

When a new message comes, the order is thus

- Service parses the response and writes it to the SQLite db
- If the app is off, a notification is created and shown to the user
- If the app is on, and the user is on the same chat thread on which a new message was sent, the `recyclerView` must be updated.
- Basically the feel is the same as whatsapp except I'm using socket.io and not XMPP

I want to use perform the CRUD operations on `SQLite` using `RxJava`.

SQLiteHelper.Class

```
public List<ChatMessage> getChatMessagesForThread(String threadName){
    List<ChatMessage>list = new ArrayList<>();
    String query = "Some Query Here";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()){

        do {
            ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage();
            message.setMessage(c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(CHAT_MESSAGES_KEY_MESSAGE))));
            message.setChatThread(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(CHAT_MESSAGES_KEY_CHAT_THREAD)));
            message.setUser(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CHAT_MESSAGES_KEY_USER)));
            list.add(message);

        } while (c.moveToNext());

    }else {
        //No such thread exists. Returns null
    }
    c.close();
    return list;
}
```

Rx Java related functions

```
    public static <T> Observable<T> makeObservable(final Callable<T> func) {
        return Observable.create(
                new Observable.OnSubscribe<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
                        try {
                            T observed = func.call();
                            if (observed != null) { // to make defaultIfEmpty work
                                subscriber.onNext(observed);
                            }
                            //TODO: DECIDE IF THIS STAYS OR NOT !!!
                            //subscriber.onCompleted();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            subscriber.onError(ex);
                        }
                    }
                }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Callable<List<ChatMessage>> getData(String threadName) {
    return new Callable() {
        public List<ChatMessage> call() {
            return getChatMessagesForThread(String threadName);
        }
    };
}


    public Observable<List<ChatMessage>> getDataObservable(String threadName) {
        return makeObservable(getData(String threadName));
    }
```

In `ChatActivity.class`

```
    databaseHelper.getDataObservable(String currentThreadName)
            .subscribe(new Action1<List<ChatMessage>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(List<ChatMessage> chatMessages) {
                    for (ChatMessage message : chatMessages){
                        //Add to list and update recyclerView
                        mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Problem is, the Rxjava call above gets executed only once and not everytime a new write operation is done.

This function is in the SQLiteHelper class and is called from my service

```
public long writeMessageToDB(ChatMessage message){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CHAT_MESSAGES_KEY_MESSAGE, message.getMessage());
    values.put(CHAT_MESSAGES_KEY_CHAT_THREAD, message.getChatThread());
    values.put(CHAT_MESSAGES_KEY_USER, message.getUser());
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.insert(CHAT_MESSAGES_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```

I have read about SQL Delite by Square but want to understand how to get the above working. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use .defer() operator if you want you observable be created each time.

```
Observable.defer(()-> Observable.just("some arg"))
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io))
.map(t -> getDataFromDb())
.map(v ->  {
     // handle your result
})
.subscribe(..);
```

Comment: Defer creates an observable only after it has at least one subscriber. A new observable is created when a new subscription is done, not when the underlying data changes. This does not solve my problem, as the subscription to the observable will be done only once in the `ChatActivity`

Comment: another way to solve that - use Realm. I'm currently using that. You can register change callback to any query and notify UI by posting event to PublishSubject or to EventBus

Comment: I have reasons to stick with SQLite. Also this will help me learn RxJava in much greater detail. Thanks anyway